# Simulated dataset for boot strapping analysis

Tags: r, random, statistics-bootstrap

My goal is to use bootstrapping (1000 reps) to calculate a null distribution, mean, and CI of r (Pearson's correlation coefficient) correlating trait (x) in 20 stimulated random pairs generated from my dataset of 600 unique individuals (ID). I have recently switched to R from SAS where I would use "proc surveyselect" to generate the dataset. Questions:

1. What would be the most efficient way to generate these results (see my attempt below)?
2. In my example, how would I use the set.seed command to replicate my results?

Simulated starting dataset with 600 individuals and the associated trait values:

```
ID <- seq(1, 600, by = 1)
x <- rnorm(600, m = 7, sd = 2)
X <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, x))
```

I then generate my 1000 replicates of r and calculate the 95% CI:

```
for (i in 1:1000) { 
  X.sample <- X[ sample(1:nrow(X), 40, replace = FALSE), ] 
  X.sample.1 <- X.sample[1:20, ]
  X.sample.2 <- X.sample[21:40, ]
  Y <- as.data.frame(cbind(X.sample.1$ID, X.sample.1$x, X.sample.2$ID,  X.sample.2$x))
  cor.results <- cor.test(Y[,2], Y[,4], alternative = c("greater"), method = c("pearson"))
  Z[i] <- cor.results$estimate
}

error <- qt(0.975, df = (length(Z) - 1)) * (sd(Z))/sqrt(length(Z))
```

Comment: Just a couple of comments re code brevity... The `ID` column appears extraneous here, but if you do want it, `ID <- 1:600` would do the trick. I can't see any reason to use a `data.frame` in this case, as your `ID` and `x` are the same data type (numeric). `matrix` operations are in general faster than `data.frame` operations, to my knowledge. See my solution below for some other time-savers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
# generate dataset
set.seed(1)
X <- rnorm(600, 7, 2)

# Create a function that samples 40 elements from X,
#  and calculates Pearson's r for the first 20 elements 
#  against the last 20 elements.
booties <- function(x) {
  X.samp <- sample(x, 40)
  cor(X.samp[1:20], X.samp[21:40])
}

# Replicate this function 1000 times (spits out a vector of cor estimates)
Z <- replicate(1000, booties(X))
error <- qt(0.975, length(Z)-1 * sd(Z)/sqrt(length(Z)))
```

1000 replicates take around 0.08 sec to complete at my end (about an order of magnitude faster than the `for` loop you were experimenting with).

Answer (score 0):

In general implicit loops are faster the explicit loops. Try taking the code inside your loop and place it in a function, and then using that function in an lapply, or sapply statement.

```
myfunction = function(<insert relevant parameters here>)
{ 
  X.sample <- X[ sample(1:nrow(X), 40, replace = FALSE), ] 
  X.sample.1 <- X.sample[1:20, ]
  X.sample.2 <- X.sample[21:40, ]
  Y <- as.data.frame(cbind(X.sample.1$ID, X.sample.1$x, X.sample.2$ID,  X.sample.2$x))
  cor.results <- cor.test(Y[,2], Y[,4], alternative = c("greater"), method = c("pearson"))
  cor.results$estimate
}

Z  = sapply(x, myfunction)
#Here every element of x contains the arguments you want to pass to my function
#You can pass multiple arguments separated by commas after the function name

error <- qt(0.975, df = (length(Z) - 1)) * (sd(Z))/sqrt(length(Z))
```

You could do this, but I find it's probably better to just use the `boot()` function in the `boot` package if you can.

As for the `set.seed()` You need to set it directly before EVERY time you generate random anything. See below.

```
> rnorm(6)
[1]  1.0915017 -0.6229437 -0.9074604 -1.5937133  0.3026445  1.6343924
> set.seed(1001)
> rnorm(6)
[1]  2.1886481 -0.1775473 -0.1852753 -2.5065362 -0.5573113 -0.1435595
> set.seed(1001)
> rnorm(6)
[1]  2.1886481 -0.1775473 -0.1852753 -2.5065362 -0.5573113 -0.1435595
> rnorm(6)
[1]  1.0915017 -0.6229437 -0.9074604 -1.5937133  0.3026445  1.6343924


> set.seed(1001)
> sample(1:5,10,replace=T)
 [1] 5 3 3 3 3 5 1 1 2 4
> sample(1:5,10,replace=T)
 [1] 3 1 5 3 2 5 1 2 1 4
> set.seed(1001)
> sample(1:5,10,replace=T)
 [1] 5 3 3 3 3 5 1 1 2 4
> rnorm(6)
[1] -0.1435595  1.0915017 -0.6229437 -0.9074604 -1.5937133  0.3026445
> set.seed(1001)
> rnorm(6)
[1]  2.1886481 -0.1775473 -0.1852753 -2.5065362 -0.5573113 -0.1435595
```

Hope that helps!

When researching the `boot` function to give you an example I ran into a snag. It only ever returns one row. Strange! I might start a new question about this. In anycase, I think the `bootstrap()` function in the `bootstrap` package will do what you are looking for. 
Here's my example

```
set.seed(1001)
X <- rnorm(600, 7, 2)


myStat <- function(x, pairs) {
index = sample(1:length(x),(pairs*2))
Z = cor(X[index[1:(length(index)/2)]], X[index[((length(index)/2)+1):length(index)]])
return(Z)
}

b=bootstrap(X,1000,myStat,pairs=20)
Z <- b$thetastar
error <- qt(0.975, length(Z)-1 * sd(Z)/sqrt(length(Z)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice. Can you make a suggestion of how to create the dataset (note good advice above the ID field is completely unnecessary) and use the boot command? I tried and that is why I feel back on the less than perfect for-loop. Thanks, Keith